# Dreamweaver changing path to site's reference instead of local

Tags: templates, relative-path, absolute-path, dreamweaver

I have noticed recently, when I apply a template to a new HTML website, all the relative paths are pointed to my local files, example: **file:///C|/webstuff/files** but I cannot set them to relative paths that are pointed to my server, **http://www.websitehere.com/** I have read that some versions of Dreamweaver will not allow this, can anyone confirm this? And if anyone knows a solution or temporary fix that'd be appreciative.

I will commonly have to "detach" the template, make the necessary changes and upload template-free but I would like to avoid doing that if possible.

Thanks

Comment: Both are absolute paths.

Comment: I edited the question, I hope it makes more sense now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior you're describing occurs when you have a new file open in Dreamweaver that has never been saved and a template applied. In other words:

1. A new file is created in DW
2. The template is applied before the file has ever been saved.
3. DW will create file paths that point to your hard drive.

The resolution is to save the file before applying the template.

Comment: thank you so much! is there anyway to fix it when i try to click, New page from template?

Comment: Its been a few years since I've used DW, but IIRC, you'll just need to create the a blank HTML (or asp, cf, php, etc...) page first, save it and then apply the template.